# Is this the same as finding the max starting at the tail of the list?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I'm wondering if this would be considered starting your comparisons at the tail end instead of the head?

```
fun maxTail [] = raise Empty 
 | maxTail [x] = x
 | maxTail (x::xs) =
      let 
        val y = maxTail xs
      in
        if x > y then x else y
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you're doing is analogous to a right fold, if that's what you mean. Note that right folds (as well as what you're doing) are not tail-recursive, so left folds are preferable.